# Configure SOAP with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I need install SOAP for PHP on my server. Looking at the documentation on the PHP manual there is only this instruction

```
To enable SOAP support, configure PHP with --enable-soap
```

Can anyone tell me how I do this? I'm assuming that I need to do this on the command line somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That means recompiling it and passing the --enable-soap switch to your ./configure script.

But you should run php -m from the command line first (or phpinfo(); ) to ensure that it's not already installed. It's a popular extension, and most hosts have it enabled by default.

If you need to compile PHP, you can find instructions on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php) for windows and linux platforms.

Comment: Yes, I've checked using php -m. SOAP is definitely not installed. I was having problems finding relevant documentation in the php manual. For anyone else finding this post I used this: http://dotjay.co.uk/2008/03/configuring-php-5-with-soap-on-media-temple-dv-35